# Read 3 Column csv into a nested Dictonary

Tags: python-3.x, csv

I had been following few example of reading csv file. I have a /some/path/file.csv as

```
type,id,password
db,db_admin,admin123
db,db_user,user123
mw,mw_admin,admin456
mw,mw_user,user456
fe,fe_admin,admin789
fe,fe_user,user789
```

Code:

```
import csv
from collections import defaultdict

types = defaultdict(list)
with open(r'/some/path/file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
  reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
  for row in reader:
  types[row['type']].append({row['id'], row['password']})
print(types)
```

Output:

```
{'db': [{'db_admin': 'admin123', 'db_user': 'user123'}],
'mw': [{'mw_admin': 'admin456', 'mw_user': 'user456'}],
'fe': [{'fe_admin': 'admin789', 'fe_user': 'user789'}]}
```

I wish to have it this way to pass it forward to a method. And how to iterate these in a loop and pass 'db' and {'db_admin': 'admin123', 'db_user': 'user123'} into a method.

```
{'db': {'db_admin': 'admin123', 'db_user': 'user123'},
'mw': {'mw_admin': 'admin456', 'mw_user': 'user456'},
'fe': {'fe_admin': 'admin789', 'fe_user': 'user789'}}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `setdefault` and create a shared entry for all the rows with the same `type` in the csv file:

```py
import csv

types = {}
with open('file.csv', 'r') as csvfile:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
    for row in reader:
        types.setdefault(row['type'], {})[row['id']] = row['password']
print(types)
```

Output

```sh
{'db': {'db_admin': 'admin123', 'db_user': 'user123'}, 'mw': {'mw_admin': 'admin456', 'mw_user': 'user456'}, 'fe': {'fe_admin': 'admin789', 'fe_user': 'user789'}}
```